# Interpretation der letzten Strophe von »Erstarrung« aus Müller-Schuberts »Winterreise«?

Tags: poetry

[Hier ist das ganze Gedicht](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Winterreise_%28Schubert/Mandyczewski%29#4._Erstarrung.), aus dem ich die letzte Strophe nicht ganz verstehe:

> Mein Herz ist wie erstorben,
>   kalt starrt ihr Bild darin:
>   schmilzt je das Herz mir wieder,
>   fliesst auch ihr Bild dahin.
>
> (Und hier singt das Ganze [DiFiDie](https://youtu.be/nOP1prcw800)).

In den ersten Gedichten des ganzen Zyklus verlässt das lyrische Ich die Stadt der Geliebten, weil sich ihr Elternhaus für einen wohlhabenderen Mann entscheidet. In diesem (dem vierten) Lied

> Es (das Ich) beschließt, ihr Bild in seinem Herzen einzuschließen und sich nie wieder zu verlieben (*schmilzt je das Herz mir wieder, fließt auch ihr Bild dahin*).

so [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winterreise#Erstarrung). Wie ist diese Interpretation mit dem Ende des Gedichts verträglich bzw. wie kommt man darauf?

Davon verstehe ich nur

> *mein Herz ist wie erstorben* → Unfähigkeit, Gefühle zu entwickeln

und

> *schmilzt je das Herz mir wieder*   → da beschreibt der Ich-Erzähler skeptisch, soll er sich wieder in jemanden verlieben, dann gilt, was er in der vierten Zeile beschreibt. Aber die verstehe ich nicht.

Comment: Bin nicht ganz sicher, was das Problem ist. _Dahin_ in der Bedeutung _weg_, _verloren_, _zunichte_? (_Unser Plan ist dahin._ _Sein Vermögen ist dahin._)

Comment: @chirlu Ja, das zusammen mit der zweiten Zeile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zunächst eine Korrektur zum Grund warum das lyrische Ich mitten im Winter die Reise antritt (Das ist wichtig für die Interpretation des ganzen Liederzyklus, und somit auch der nachgefragten Zeilen):

Die Tochter des Hauses war ihm schon zugesagt (»Das Mädchen sprach von Liebe, die Mutter gar von Eh’«), aber das Mädchen (und nicht deren Eltern) hat sich dann doch für einen anderen entschieden (»Die Liebe liebt das Wandern, Gott hat sie so gemacht, von Einem zu dem Andern«. An dieser Stelle ist unklar, ob mit »Liebe« das Mädchen oder das Gefühl gemeint ist.) (Zitate aus »Gute Nacht«, dem ersten Lied des Zyklus)

Jetzt zur eigentlichen Frage:

> Mein Herz ist wie erstorben

Dadurch, dass sich das Mädchen vom jungen Gesellen abgewandt hat, fühlt er sich so tief getroffen, als hätte jemand sein Herz durchstoßen. Das heißt nicht, dass er gefühlskalt geworden wäre, sondern dass er die Kälte des Mädchens fühlt, die ihn wegen eines anderen verlassen hat.

> kalt starrt ihr Bild darin

Doch er kann sie nicht vergessen. Er liebt sie, die Kalte, noch immer.

> schmilzt je das Herz mir wieder
>   fliesst auch ihr Bild, ihr Bild dahin

Sollte sich der Zustandes seines Herzens je wieder bessern, dann nur, wenn er das Mädchen vergisst, aber das scheint derzeit unmöglich zu sein.

Comment: Im zweiten Lied erscheint aber "*Was fragen sie nach meinen Schmerzen? Ihr Kind ist eine reiche Braut*". Ist es nicht eben das, was bestimmt, dass denen die Beziehung vom Vater (der Braut) aufgrund Wohlstandes verboten ist? Und jetzt die Braut eines reicheren Mannes geworden ist?

Comment: @c.p.: Deine Interpretation passt nicht zu den beiden von mir zitierten Ausschnitten. Eine Braut ist eine verlobte, also noch unverheiratete Frau. Wenn eine Braut reich ist, ist sie es nicht weil ihr zukünftiger Mann reich ist, sondern weil sie selbst aus reichem Hause kommt. Der Satz »*Was fragen sie nach meinen Schmerzen? Ihr Kind ist eine reiche Braut*« bedeutet nur, dass sich die Eltern wegen der Trennung keine Sorgen um ihre Tochter machen müssen

Comment: Gut. Deine Interpretation ergibt besseren Sinn. Dann ist die Interpretation von Wikipedia falsch...

Answer (score 2):

Ich bemühe hier einfach mal ein anderes Bild:

Das Bild der Geliebten ist wie in Eis eingefroren, mit dem Abschmelzen des Eises (= emotionale Erstarrung) schmilzt es weg, wie ein Relief im Eis schmelzen würde, keine Spuren hinterlassend, wodurch das lyrische Ich frei für eine neue Liebe würde.

Answer (score 2):

> mein Herz ist wie erstorben → Unfähigkeit, Gefühle zu entwickeln

Nein. Ich denke der Vers drückt eher die aktuelle Trauer aus.

Erst im dritten Vers

> schmilzt je das Herz mir wieder

wird (auch durch das je und wieder) ein Ausblick auf die Zukunft eingeleitet.

---

Ich stimme nicht mit der Interpretation von Wikpedia überein und lese **nicht** aus den letzten beiden Zeilen ab, dass sich das Ich nie wieder verlieben wird oder dies beschließt. Es zeigt meiner Meinung nach lediglich die in diesem Fall eintretende Konsequenz auf: die alte Liebe zu vergessen. Ob es im konkreten Fall bereit sein wird dies zu tun, bleibt offen, da es wohl auch von der konkreten Zukunft abhängt.